# To Bind RadGrid Dynamically

Tags: radgridview

I using Telerik tool. I need to change my itemsource and selected item of the RadGrid dynamically
   Can any one guide me  how to Bind selected item and Itemsource of the Grid in CodeBehind.
 I posted Support in Telerik ,but they didn't reply me properly. Its urgent, Please guide me..

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Set the ItemsSource an ICollectionView. I define a property like this in my view model:

public ICollectionView ProductsCollectionView { get; set; }

After the service call I set it like this:

_internalSpecificationCollection = new ObservableCollection(e.Results);
ProductsCollectionView= new PagedCollectionView(_internalCollection);

You can also then add a Telerik data pager and also bind this to the ICollectionView.

You then have access to the event ICollectionView.CurrentChanged in which you can get the ICollectionView.CurrentItem